# Continuous map of differentiable manifolds is differentiable if differentiable functions pull back to differentiable functions

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

This is Exercise 3.1.A. in [Vakil's notes](http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/FOAGdec3014public.pdf)

> Suppose that $\pi: X\rightarrow Y$ is a continuous map of differentiable manifolds. Show that $\pi$ is differentiable if differentialble functions pull back to differentiable functions, i.e., if pullback by $\pi$ gives mpa $\mathcal{O}_Y\rightarrow \pi_*\mathcal{O}_X$.

Let $f: V\subseteq Y\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function on an open subset of $Y$. Let $(U,\phi)$ be a chart of $X$, $(V,\psi)$ be a chart of $Y$. Then $f\circ\pi(\phi^{-1})$ is differentiable and $f\circ\psi^{-1}$ is differentiable. We need to show that $\psi\circ\pi\circ\phi^{-1}$ is differentiable. I don't know how to prove this.

Can we say that since $(U,\psi\circ\pi)$ constructs a chart of $X$, by the compatibility, $\psi\circ\pi\circ\phi^{-1}$ is differentiable? This seems true but this does not use the fact that $f$ is differentiable.

Sorry I have no background of Differentiable Manifolds. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry I accidentally submitted twice.

Comment: Don't worry! We wait for the moderation. ;)